# How to prove unbiasedness/consistency/normality of an estimator that doesn't have a closed form?

Tags: estimation, bias, asymptotics

My estimator looks like this:

$$
\hat\theta(X) = \arg\max_{\theta} \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N f(x_n|\theta)
$$

Here, $f(x_n|\theta)$ is some arbitrary function: it's *not* a logarithm, and the sum is *not* a log-likelihood.

I don't think that there's a closed form expression for $\hat\theta(X)$, so I'm using numerical optimization (gradient descent, Newton's method) to find it. However, this doesn't seem to let me calculate the expectation $\mathbb{E}\hat\theta(X)$ to prove even unbiasedness of the estimator.

How does one theoretically (without simulations) prove that such an estimator is (un)biased, (in)consistent, (non-)normal and so on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your estimator is what's known as an [M-estimator of $\rho$-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator#Definition), where in this case $\rho = -f$.

If your function $f$ is differentiable, then it is known that under some (fairly strong) conditions, the M-estimator is consistent for the true maximizer of $f$, and is in fact asymptotically normal. See Chapter 7 of Boos & Stefanski's *Essential Statistical Inference* (2013) for a detailed treatment of M-estimation.

Answer (score 8):

On a [general basis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/322096/7224), $\hat\theta(X)$ is biased, due to the fact that it is equivariant under reparameterisation, i.e., if$$\eta=h(\theta)$$ is another parameterisation of the model, with $h$ a bijection, then $$\hat\eta(X)=h(\hat\theta(X))$$ while unbiasedness does not carry under arbitrary transforms $h$.

Note also that most parameters (or parameterisations) do not allow for the [existence of an unbiased estimator](https://www.eng.biu.ac.il/spiral/files/2017/07/unbiased-doublecolumn-IT-2-FINAL_2.pdf), see e.g. the $\eta=1/p$ example [for the Binomial model](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681638/14893).